# Regular expression in C# for Number with Decimal Point & Commas

Tags: c#, regex

I need to enter amount in a textbox which allows numbers with decimal point and commas.
What is the regular expression for this?

I used the below

`txtInitialAmountGuarDetails.ValidationSettings.RegularExpression.ValidationExpression 
= @"^[-+]?\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9])(|,\d*[0-9])?$";`

But it not working for large numbers like 300,000,000,000,000.

Answer (score 7):

Build it up piecemeal. Given a US locale, a number with these rules has in order:

- The string beginning: `^`
- An optional sign: `[+-]?`
- Up to 3 digits: `\d{1,3}`
- A comma followed by 3 digits, repeated any number of times: `(?:,\d{3})*`
- An optional decimal point and decimal part: `(?:[.]\d+)?`
- The string end: `$`

Do you have restrictions on the number of digits after the decimal point?  Then change the last plus sign to {`2}` for 2 digits.

So, the regex is:

```
@"^[+-]?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:[.]\d+)?$"
```

Or, if you want to explain your work, use the `x` option and:

```
@"(?x)            # Extended format.
  ^[+-]?          # Optional sign.
  \d{1,3}         # Initial 1-3 digits.
  (?:,\d{3})*     # Any number of commas followed by 3 digits.
  (?:[.]\d+)?$"   # An optional decimal point followed by any number of digits.
```

But does C# have a locale-dependent validator already?

Comment: I'm not aware of a locale aware validator for numbers like this. You could use `CultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator` and other properties to create the regular expression based on a locale.

Comment: There are all sorts of interesting cultures.  India formats numbers with pairs of digits separated by commas with a final 3-digit sequence and then the fractional part: `12,34,567.89`.

Comment: NumberGroupSizes would then return {3,2}, i.e. first group has 3 digits, next groups have 2. But getting all that into a regular expression would not be a trivial task.

Comment: The square brackets around the decimal point are redundant. They represent a 'Character Group' which indicates that any character within the character group can be present. A character group with just a single character can be replaced by the character itself.

Comment: @Scott Munro, I used `[.]` because I prefer that to escaping the metacharacter `.` with backslashes. I'm never sure how many to use, depending on the language I'm writing in. In Perl, I'd need only one.  In Java, I'd need two, and, as a commenter pointed out above, with the `@""` string format, I'd only need one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think that I will probably stick with the escapes but I can definitely see where you are coming from.

Comment: Well, when you use many languages over 30 years of work, your memory goes, and they all blend into each other.  C# is fresh to you; do what is optimal for it.

Answer (score 1):

I have not run it, but you can try it out.

```
var regexp =/^\s*?([\d\,]+(\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})\s*$/;
```

Comment: The question isn't about javascript :-)

Comment: but regular expression your can use

Comment: RegularExpression.ValidationExpression = @"^\s*?([\d\,]+(\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})\s*$";

Comment: also OP didn't mention leading and trailing `\s`

Comment: @DeepakSaralaya, handle +/- signs too.

Answer (score 1):

This works: `\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.{0,1}(\d{3},)*\d{0,3}`

As for the after the comma issue, any choice should be fine. If you go with commas, my regex works. If you do  5 digits then a space just replace the end with `(\d{5}\s{1})*\d{0,5}`. And ofcourse if you just dont use any deliminator after the decimal you just put `\d*`

Comment: People normally don't have commas after the decimal point. I've seen spaces after every block of five sometimes.  And `(\d,{3})` matches `6,,,`, which I don't think you intended.

Comment: @EricJablow Whoops, yeah, thats a typo. Ill fix that now. As for commas after the decimal, I cant really say either way, but it should be a quick fix for whatever style you choose.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex too:

```
^([+-]?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*(?:\.\d+)*)$
```

Keep in mind `.` has a specific meaning in regex engine so it is necessary to escape it.

I would also suggest you to not use regex for this task instead look at [masked textbox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14837/Xtended-TextBox).

Comment: I like using `[.]` instead of `\.` for literal periods.  But then, I program in Java these days, and Java has no raw strings; you need to write `\\.` to get the regex `\.`.

Comment: @EricJablow, thank you for sharing such info related to Java, but if you have noticed OP has tagged C#, and AFAIK C# supports literal and `string pattern = @"^([+-]?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*(?:\.\d+)*)$"` would compile without any issue. If `@` is excluded from above snippet then really `\\.` is required.

Comment: Exactly.  Since the OP is using C#, he doesn't have to worry about backslashitis.  But the problem in general is of interest to all--it is tagged "regex".  We can all learn from each other, even if it's to say "No, I will never program in *that* language."

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
^([0-9]{3}[,.]|)+[0-9]{0,3}$
```

let me know if it needs any enhancements...

Comment: Nope, still wouldn't work. Now 999.999.999.999.999 works. You need to require 1 or 0 decimal points. You can use this site to quickly test your regexes: http://regexpal.com/